# SPI Control of TMC5160-BOB using ESP32-S2 Feather

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, motor-controller, esp32, stepper-driver

I am unable to drive a motor with the TMC5160-BOB using SPI commands. Anybody understand why?

Block Diagram:
[image: Block Diagram]

Arduino C Code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <TMC5160.h>

const u_int8_t SPI_CS = 5; // CS pin in SPI mode
const u_int8_t SPI_DRV_ENN = 4;  // DRV_ENN pin in SPI mode
const u_int8_t target_register = 0x2D; // Register to attempt read/write. 0x2D is "XTARGET"
const u_int8_t write_value1 = 200; // First value to write to register.
const u_int8_t write_value2 = 100; // Second value to write to register.
char buffer[100]; // Buffer to hold formatted strings

TMC5160_SPI motor = TMC5160_SPI(SPI_CS); //Use default SPI peripheral and SPI settings.
SPISettings mySPISettings(9600, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3);

  void writeInt_40bit(uint8_t address, int value){
    uint8_t tbuf[5];
    tbuf[0] = address | 0x80;
    tbuf[1] = 0xFF & (value>>24);
    tbuf[2] = 0xFF & (value>>16);
    tbuf[3] = 0xFF & (value>>8);
    tbuf[4] = 0xFF & value;

    SPI.beginTransaction(mySPISettings);
    digitalWrite(SPI_CS, LOW); // Pull CS low to start transmission
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      SPI.transfer(tbuf[i]);
    }
    digitalWrite(SPI_CS, HIGH); // Pull CS high to end transmission
    SPI.endTransaction();
  }

  int readInt_40bit(uint8_t address){
    uint8_t tbuf[5], rbuf[5];
    int value = 0;
    // clear write bit
    tbuf[0] = address & 0x7F;
    
    SPI.beginTransaction(mySPISettings);
    digitalWrite(SPI_CS, LOW); // Pull CS low to start transmission
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      rbuf[i] = SPI.transfer(tbuf[i]);
    }
    digitalWrite(SPI_CS, HIGH); // Pull CS high to end transmission
    SPI.endTransaction();

    value = rbuf[1];
    value <<= 8;
    value |= rbuf[2];
    value <<= 8;
    value |= rbuf[3];
    value <<= 8;
    value |= rbuf[4];

    return value;
  }


void setup(){
  // USB/debug serial coms
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("\n\nSetup print statements are working.");

  pinMode(SPI_DRV_ENN, OUTPUT); 
  digitalWrite(SPI_DRV_ENN, LOW); // Active low

  SPI.begin();
  delay(1000);

  sprintf(buffer, "\nInitial register %X value: %X\n", 0x20, readInt_40bit(0x20));
  Serial.println(buffer);

  // Write all other setup registers
  writeInt_40bit(0x24, 1000); // A1 = 1000 First acceleration 
  writeInt_40bit(0x25, 5000); // V1 = 50000 Acceleration threshold velocity V1 
  writeInt_40bit(0x26, 500); // AMAX = 500 Acceleration above V1 
  writeInt_40bit(0x27, 200000); // VMAX = 200000 
  writeInt_40bit(0x28, 700); // DMAX = 700 Deceleration above V1 
  writeInt_40bit(0x2A, 1400); // D1 = 1400 Deceleration below V1 
  writeInt_40bit(0x2B, 10); // VSTOP = 10 Stop velocity (Near to zero) 
  writeInt_40bit(0x20, 0); // RAMPMODE = 0 (Target position move)   

  sprintf(buffer, "Final register %X value: %X\n", 0x20, readInt_40bit(0x20));
  Serial.println(buffer);
}


void loop() {
  digitalWrite(SPI_CS, LOW); // Select the TMC5160 driver by setting its CS pin low

  // Print the second (or initial) register data to the serial monitor
  u_int8_t readResponse = readInt_40bit(target_register); // Read target register
  Serial.print("Read data 2: ");
  Serial.println(readResponse, HEX);

  // Write first value to target register
  Serial.print("Writing ");
  Serial.println(write_value1, HEX);
  writeInt_40bit(target_register, write_value1);

  // Print the first read data to the serial monitor
  readResponse = readInt_40bit(target_register); // Read target register
  Serial.print("Read data 1: ");
  Serial.println(readResponse, HEX);

  // Write second value to target register
  Serial.print("Writing ");
  Serial.println(write_value2, HEX);
  writeInt_40bit(target_register, write_value2);

  // Reading motor position
  sprintf(buffer, "XTARGET (%d) value: %d;   XACTUAL (%d) value: %d", 0x2d, readInt_40bit(0x2D), 0x21, readInt_40bit(0x21));
  Serial.println(buffer);

  digitalWrite(SPI_CS, HIGH); // Deselect the TMC5160 driver by setting its CS pin high

  delay(1000); // Delay for clarity
  Serial.print("Message repeats.\n\n");
}
```

**Output**

```
Read data 2: FC
Writing C8
Read data 1: C8
Writing 64
XTARGET (45) value: 100;   XACTUAL (33) value: 1067981820
Message repeats.
```

**Observations/Results:**
XACTUAL appears to receive an SPI write, and then return the written value. There are no voltage drops or other suspicious behavior in the V+ lines. However, datasheet initialization and motor movement example does not succeed on the TMC5160-BOB. I see very little current draw on my power supply when the motor should be spinning.

**Datasheets**
[Trinamic TMC5160-BOB](https://www.trinamic.com/support/eval-kits/details/tmc5160-bob/)
[Adafruit ESP32-S2 Feather](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-esp32-s2-feather/overview)
[Motor (QSH5718-76-28-189)](https://www.trinamic.com/fileadmin/assets/Products/Motors_Documents/QSH5718_Manual_Rev2.4.pdf)

Comment: A schematic and layout of your set up would be good (a block diagram doesn't give enough detail if you have connected something wrong). What about your motor? What is it, what's it rated to, where's its datasheet?

Comment: I added a link to the motor datasheet - thanks for pointing that out! You can see the part number for it above the coil cartoons at the bottom right of the block diagram. The datasheet says it's rated for 2.8A RMS, and "up to 75V" operational voltage, but also that it's "rated to 3.5V" and at one point suggests 24V.

As far as schematics go - the block diagram has all the connections I made. I didn't modify any of the dev boards, so any remaining detail will be at hand if you're looking at a datasheet.